# What happens when minmax is: minmax(auto, auto)

Tags: css, css-grid

In the bottom of this article ([How the minmax() Function Works](https://bitsofco.de/how-the-minmax-function-works/))  it says for `minmax(auto, auto)`:

> If used as a maximum, the auto value is equivalent to the max-content value. If used as a minimum, the auto value represents the largest minimum size the cell can be. This “largest minimum size” is different from the min-content value, and specified by min-width/min-height.

Would someone mind eleborating on the difference between `min-content` and the auto here that’s ‘specified by min-width/min-height’?

I understand min-content to be smallest possible width the cell can be that does not lead to an overflow. What does ‘specified by min-width/min-height’ mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an illustration of your quote:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, 10px) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container>div {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div style="min-width:200px;">some text</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, when I added `min-width:200px` the `auto` will consider that value and will be bigger than the max (10px) and the result will be `200px` because

> If the max is less than the min, then the max will be floored by the min (essentially yielding `minmax(min, min)`).  <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#valdef-grid-template-columns-minmax)</sup>

---

If you use `min-content` you can clearly see the difference

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, 10px) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container>div {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div style="min-width:200px;">some text</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

`min-content` will be bigger than `10px` and will be used to define the size while in the first example (without min-width) `auto` will compute to `0`

When using `minmax(auto,auto)` it will be different and you will have the following:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(auto, auto) 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container>div {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div style="min-width:200px;">some text</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

> representing the range between the minimum and maximum described above. (This behaves similar to `minmax(min-content, max-content)` in the most basic cases, but with extra abilities.)

---

Below and interactive Demo to better see the difference between the use of `auto`, `min-content`, `max-content`

Resize and see how it behaves in each case.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 300px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container>div {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="grid-template-columns:minmax(auto,auto) minmax(auto,auto)">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="grid-template-columns:minmax(min-content,max-content) minmax(min-content,max-content);">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="grid-template-columns:minmax(auto,40%) minmax(auto,40%)">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="grid-template-columns:minmax(min-content,40%) minmax(min-content,40%)">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="grid-template-columns:minmax(30%,max-content) minmax(30%,max-content)">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="grid-template-columns:minmax(30%,auto) minmax(30%,auto)">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it's better to add `justify-content: flex-start;` to the last example to be illustrate the behavior of `auto`, as `auto` tracks get stretched by default. Don't you think ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak I indeed want them to stretch :) so we can see the difference bettween auto and max-content and understand this part of the Spec *however, unlike max-content, allows expansion of the track by the align-content and justify-content properties.* and to also understand *This behaves similar to minmax(min-content, max-content) in the most basic cases, but with extra abilities.)* [note the *with extra abilities]

Comment: I agree but we lose the visual difference of when `auto` is acting like `max-content`

Comment: @ZohirSalak that's why I made them resizable so we can see the *small* difference on different width.

Comment: That is alot of example without really answering the question. Your code examples even contradict the statements in your answer: *minmax(auto, auto) behaves similar to minmax(min-content, max-content) in the most basic cases, but with extra abilities.* while clearly the outcome in your extremely basic example are totally different. Also you don't explain the difference at all. Unfortunately the code results do not speak for themselves with this.

Comment: @connexo I already answered the main question in the first example to show how the *specified by min-width/min-heigh* affect the definition of auto. Everything else is extra and there is no contradiction in my statements. There is two parts (1) *behave similar to* AND (2) *with extra abilities* --> if you resize the examples you will clearly notice how they behave similar in a certain range AND how they are different when the width is big which will make auto have the *extra ability* to stretch.